# how extract email from fb html c#

Tags: c#

Facebook emails in html page will show as below.

```
<ul class="uiList _4kg">

<li>

rezarezvan110&#064;hotmail.com

<span class="pls inlineLabel">(Windows Live Messenger)</span>

</li>

 <li>

<a href="ymsgr:sendim?yasin_zfarzaneh%40yahoo.com">

    <span>yasin_zfarzaneh&#064;yaho</span>

    <wbr />

    <span class="word_break">

    </span>o.com
</a>

<span class="pls inlineLabel">(Yahoo! Messenger)</span>

</li>
```

know i want extracted email of it , how can i do it ? 
 i used this method but dont return anything

```
 public static List<string> Fetch_Emails1(string Sourcecode)
    {
        List<string> Emails = new List<string>();


      Regex exp = new Regex(@".*?(&#064;)", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
        MatchCollection matchCollection = exp.Matches(Sourcecode);

        foreach (Match m in matchCollection)
        {

            Emails.Add(m.Value);

        }



        return Emails;
    }
```

how change pattern for extract email ?

Comment: Your regex not matching cause there is no `@` symbol in `yasin_zfarzaneh%40yahoo.com`

Comment: You gave to use a html decoder first. by the way, can you share the exact html ?

Comment: first load fb page in webbrowser so send to method documenttext and decode it , also i remove tag of html . so extract email from it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basing your code on another web application's page parsing is error prone and very difficult to maintain. Imagine that if facebook changes the rendered HTML, your application won't work.

I would strongly suggest to use some [facebook API](https://developers.facebook.com/). Check [facebook SDK for .NET](http://facebooksdk.net/) or [Facebook API for C#.NET developers on codeplex](http://facebookapi.codeplex.com/).

Regarding the emails, you have to check the permissions issue. [This post](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions) gives details.

Hope I helped!

Comment: i used facbook api for extract my firend list , but i cant find any api for extract email from facebook :(